# typeerror 'nonetype' object is not callable selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

**Code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver=webdriver.Chrome('H:\datascience-python\selinium\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://www.aljazeera.com/news/')

button = driver.find_element_by_id('btn_showmore_b1_418')

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)

content = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')

container = soup.select('div.topics-sec-item-cont')

titlelist = []

urllist = []

for items in  container:

    if items is not None:

        title = items.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="col-sm-7 topics-sec-item-cont"]/a/h2').text

        url = items.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="col-sm-7 topics-sec-item-cont"]/a')

        titlelist.append(title)

        urllist.append(url.get_attribute('href'))

        print(str(titlelist) + '\n')

        print(str(urllist) + '\n')
```

**Error:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-1-acf307cfccb3> in <module>

     18 for items in  container:

     19     if items is not None:

---> 20         title = items.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="col-sm-7 topics-sec-item-cont"]/a/h2').text

     21         url = items.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="col-sm-7 topics-sec-item-cont"]/a')

     22 

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
title = items.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="col-sm-7 topics-sec-item-cont"]/a/h2').text
```

the xpath provided in this line of code is not returning object.
This issue can arise only because of two reason:

1. Either the provided xpath is wrong.
2. The div that you are trying to extract from is not yet loaded completely.